# When serializaing a collection of objects that each contains a reference to another object in the collection, what will it do?

Tags: java, serialization, collections, reference

So, all of the objects are being serialized, but each one contains a reference to another object(of the same type) in the collection.  I think I should name it transient, store a string that could be used to get the object again upon deserialization, then restore it at that point.  In that case though, would I do that in the overwritten readObject method?  If that explanation makes sense, can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do this.  Java's serialization can handle circular references.  Both ObjectInputStream and ObjectObjectStream keeps track of objects that they have already processed to prevent infinite serialization loops.  This can lead to a memory leak if you hold on to the streams for a long time.

Comment: Oh sweet thanks.  I was wondering if it could do this since it has to be able to serialize double linked lists.  But what do you mean by holding on to the stream for to long?  Just serializing to and from a file is okay, right?

Comment: @Brody right. If you were exchanging objects over an open connection you would want to look into ObjectOutputStream.reset() or ObjectOutputStream..writeUnshared().